# In a random walk starting at A and then moving to any adjacent point with equal probability. Find P(reach B before E)

Tags: probability, random

[image]It seems to me that for symmetric reasons the answer should be $\frac{1}{2}$.
I tried to prove this by separating paths that did not include A and those that did.
The probability of the former is $\frac{3}{8}$ (using the sum of an infinite geometric sequence) and the probability of the latter seems to me to be $\frac{1}{2}$$\frac{1}{3}$P where P is the requested probability.(the $\frac{1}{2}$ comes from going from A to C or D and the $\frac{1}{3}$ from going from those back to A). This "recursive" equation results in $P=\frac{18}{40}$ which is not expected. Will be grateful for any thoughts on this

Comment: I know. Just managed to add it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is "obviously" $\frac12$ by symmetry.

Let's try a longer way: let $P_i$ be the probability that you reach $B$ before $E$ when starting from point $i$.  Then

- $P_A=\frac14 P_B + \frac14 P_C + \frac14 P_D + \frac14 P_E$
- $P_B=1$
- $P_C=\frac13 P_A + \frac13 P_B + \frac13 P_D$
- $P_D=\frac13 P_A + \frac13 P_C + \frac13 P_E$
- $P_E=0$

which is five equations in five unknowns.  You can solve them by substitution or otherwise and get the unique solution

- $P_A=\frac12$
- $P_B=1$
- $P_C=\frac58$
- $P_D=\frac38$
- $P_E=0$

Comment: Thanks. Interesting answer. Would you change your solution if the question is not limited to the shortest path but can continue endlessly? (This is in fact explicitly stated in the question-sorry for not emphasizing this). Also can you find the fault in my reasoning above?

Comment: @Elazar My answer only deals with the potentially unlimited number of steps problem (though note the walk will eventually reach either $B$ or $E$ with probability $1$).  The issue with your attempt was that it covered going from $A$ to $C$ and back to $A$ but not going from $A$ to $C$ and then to $D$ with the next step possibly going to $A$ or $C$; my approach resolves that

Comment: Your right. This adds another infinite geometric sum into the equation. Thanks a lot